# Accessing a div nested in multiple elements using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a web interaction using the selenium library in python (I'm a beginner). This is some of the html code of the button I'd like the code to automatically press:

```
<div class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiAccordionSummary-expandIcon MuiIconButton-edgeEnd" aria-disabled="false" aria-hidden="true"><span class="MuiIconButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></div>
```

I tried writing a function that iterates through every child of each html parent in the website, and finds the one with the element's class:

```
def find_element_by_class(driver, class_name):

    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*")

    def search_element(elements):
        for element in elements:
            if element.get_attribute("class") == class_name:
                return element
            else:
                child_elements = element.find_elements(By.XPATH, "./*")
                if child_elements:
                    found_element = search_element(child_elements)
                    if found_element:
                        return found_element
        return None

    return search_element(elements)

element = find_element_by_class(driver, "MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiAccordionSummary-expandIcon Mui-expanded MuiIconButton-edgeEnd")
element.click()
```

I was expecting the function to find the right element and click it. Instead, the connection just times out (possibly because the function takes too long to finish). Is there any better way to do this, or did I go wrong somewhere?